# Sort XML by elements and then by value of sub-element

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

my knowledge is XSLT is sadly a "little bit limited", but maybe one an help or show the way:

This is my basic XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Topobase>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
    <ID>13</ID>
    <AUTOGRIDORDER>1</AUTOGRIDORDER>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG>
  <FORMS_VERSION>
    <Version>11000011</Version>
  </FORMS_VERSION>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>32304</ID>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ID>32305</ID>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
    <ID>1543</ID>
    <AUTOGRIDORDER>1</AUTOGRIDORDER>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG>
.....
```

The idea is to sort twice:
a) The main elements should be sorted alphabetically into "groups":

```
<Topobase>
  <FORMS_VERSION>
...
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
....
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
....
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...
```

b) Inside the grouped elements, they should be sorted by

```
 <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...<ID>13</ID>...
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...<ID>28</ID>...
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...<ID>542</ID>...
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
...<ID>678</ID>...
```

I found here some XSLT going into this direction, but some are only by name or only by attribute. but this strange mixture of "groups" and sub-elements could be a little bit tricky.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Added Full XML-Example

````
<Topobase>
  <FORMS_VERSION>
    <Version>11000011</Version>
  </FORMS_VERSION>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG>
    <ID>1175</ID>
    <AUTOGRIDORDER>1</AUTOGRIDORDER>
    <AUTOTABORDER>1</AUTOTABORDER>
    <CAPTION>Normschacht</CAPTION>
    <DEFAULTHEIGHT>1022</DEFAULTHEIGHT>
    <DEFAULTISDOCKED>0</DEFAULTISDOCKED>
    <DEFAULTLEFT>1820</DEFAULTLEFT>
    <DEFAULTMODE>1</DEFAULTMODE>
    <DEFAULTTAB>1</DEFAULTTAB>
    <DEFAULTTABSVISIBLE>1</DEFAULTTABSVISIBLE>
    <DEFAULTTOP>85</DEFAULTTOP>
    <DEFAULTWIDTH>893</DEFAULTWIDTH>
    <DETAILHEIGHT>100</DETAILHEIGHT>
    <DIALOGNAME>WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE</DIALOGNAME>
    <REGISTERNAMES>Normschacht;Weitere;</REGISTERNAMES>
    <STARTMODE>0</STARTMODE>
    <TABGROUPSUSPEND>||</TABGROUPSUSPEND>
    <TABLENAME>WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE</TABLENAME>
    <TOOLBAR_ID>1</TOOLBAR_ID>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26851</ID>
    <ALIGNRIGHT>1</ALIGNRIGHT>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>0</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>T2t_fid_contact_owner:</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>TextBox</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLUMNNAME>T2T_FID_CONTACT_OWNER</COLUMNNAME>
    <COLWIDTH>200</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <ENFORCEUPPER>0</ENFORCEUPPER>
    <FILESELECTION>0</FILESELECTION>
    <FILTERCOMBOBOX>0</FILTERCOMBOBOX>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <ISLOCKED>0</ISLOCKED>
    <ISOBLIGATE>0</ISOBLIGATE>
    <ISUNIQUE>0</ISUNIQUE>
    <LEFT>160</LEFT>
    <MULTILINE>0</MULTILINE>
    <NAME>T2T_FID_CONTACT_OWNER</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>0</TABID>
    <TOP>1401</TOP>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
    <WORDWRAP>0</WORDWRAP>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26852</ID>
    <ALLOWDOUBLECLICK>1</ALLOWDOUBLECLICK>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>0</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>ID - Material Benutzerdefiniert:</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>ComboBox</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLUMNNAME>ID_MATERIAL_USER</COLUMNNAME>
    <COLWIDTH>200</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DETAILFIELDNAME>ID</DETAILFIELDNAME>
    <DETAILFILTER>ACTIVE=1</DETAILFILTER>
    <DETAILLIST>VALUE</DETAILLIST>
    <DETAILORDERBY>VALUE</DETAILORDERBY>
    <DETAILTABLE>WW_PO_MATERIAL_USER_TBD</DETAILTABLE>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <FIDBUTTON>0</FIDBUTTON>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <HIGHLIGHTBUTTON>0</HIGHLIGHTBUTTON>
    <ISLOCKED>0</ISLOCKED>
    <ISOBLIGATE>0</ISOBLIGATE>
    <ISUNIQUE>0</ISUNIQUE>
    <LEFT>160</LEFT>
    <NAME>ID_MATERIAL_USER</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>0</TABID>
    <TOP>1428</TOP>
    <USEBUFFER>1</USEBUFFER>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26853</ID>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>0</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>Ww_po_fi_fitting:</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>Reference</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLWIDTH>200</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DETAILFIELDNAME>FID_FEATURE</DETAILFIELDNAME>
    <DETAILTABLE>WW_PO_FI_FITTING</DETAILTABLE>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <LEFT>160</LEFT>
    <MASTERFIELDNAME>FID</MASTERFIELDNAME>
    <NAME>$REF_WW_PO_FI_FITTING</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <PROJECTIONBUTTON>1</PROJECTIONBUTTON>
    <REFERENCEBUTTON>1</REFERENCEBUTTON>
    <TABID>0</TABID>
    <TOP>1455</TOP>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26763</ID>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>1</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CLASSNAME>ApiControl</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLWIDTH>70</COLWIDTH>
    <CUSTOMPROPS>ControlProperties||</CUSTOMPROPS>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <ISOBLIGATE>0</ISOBLIGATE>
    <LEFT>570</LEFT>
    <NAME>$STARTINGLINES</NAME>
    <PLUGINASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.dll</PLUGINASSEMBLYNAME>
    <PLUGINCLASSNAME>BUTTON</PLUGINCLASSNAME>
    <PLUGINCLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms</PLUGINCLASSNAMESPACE>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>2</TABID>
    <TOP>313</TOP>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26764</ID>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>1</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CLASSNAME>Line</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLWIDTH>200</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <FORECOLOR>Gray</FORECOLOR>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <LEFT>80</LEFT>
    <LINESIZE>1</LINESIZE>
    <MULTILINE>0</MULTILINE>
    <NAME>$LINEVERBUNDENE</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>9</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>1</TABID>
    <TOP>733</TOP>
    <VERTICAL>0</VERTICAL>
    <WIDTH>690</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26765</ID>
    <ALIGNRIGHT>0</ALIGNRIGHT>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>1</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CLASSNAME>Label</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLWIDTH>40</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <FONTNAME>Microsoft Sans Serif</FONTNAME>
    <FONTSIZE>8</FONTSIZE>
    <FONTSTYLE>0</FONTSTYLE>
    <FORECOLOR>Black</FORECOLOR>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <LEFT>0</LEFT>
    <NAME>$LABELVERBUNDENE</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>1</TABID>
    <TEXT>Verbundene</TEXT>
    <TOP>733</TOP>
    <WIDTH>80</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26766</ID>
    <ALIGNRIGHT>1</ALIGNRIGHT>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>1</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>Sohlenkote:</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>TextBox</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLUMNNAME>BOTTOM_ELEVATION</COLUMNNAME>
    <COLWIDTH>84</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <ENFORCEUPPER>0</ENFORCEUPPER>
    <FILESELECTION>0</FILESELECTION>
    <FILTERCOMBOBOX>0</FILTERCOMBOBOX>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <ISLOCKED>0</ISLOCKED>
    <ISOBLIGATE>0</ISOBLIGATE>
    <ISUNIQUE>0</ISUNIQUE>
    <LEFT>170</LEFT>
    <MULTILINE>0</MULTILINE>
    <NAME>BOTTOM_ELEVATION</NAME>
    <NEXTCONTROL>ID_MATERIAL</NEXTCONTROL>
    <PRECISION>3</PRECISION>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>1</TABID>
    <TOOLTIPTEXT>Meter. Leer, wenn unbekannt.</TOOLTIPTEXT>
    <TOP>453</TOP>
    <WIDTH>60</WIDTH>
    <WORDWRAP>0</WORDWRAP>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26767</ID>
    <ALIGNRIGHT>0</ALIGNRIGHT>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>1</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>Erstellungsdatum: (*)</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>TextBox</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLUMNNAME>DATE_CREATION</COLUMNNAME>
    <COLWIDTH>129</COLWIDTH>
    <DATEFORMAT>d</DATEFORMAT>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <ENFORCEUPPER>0</ENFORCEUPPER>
    <FILESELECTION>0</FILESELECTION>
    <FILTERCOMBOBOX>0</FILTERCOMBOBOX>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <ISLOCKED>0</ISLOCKED>
    <ISOBLIGATE>0</ISOBLIGATE>
    <ISUNIQUE>0</ISUNIQUE>
    <LEFT>570</LEFT>
    <MULTILINE>0</MULTILINE>
    <NAME>DATE_CREATION</NAME>
    <NEXTCONTROL>DATE_MODIFICATION</NEXTCONTROL>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <TABID>1</TABID>
    <TOP>173</TOP>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
    <WORDWRAP>0</WORDWRAP>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_CONTROL>
    <ID>26768</ID>
    <ALLOWREFERENCE>1</ALLOWREFERENCE>
    <ASSEMBLYNAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DLL</ASSEMBLYNAME>
    <BASEVISIBILITY>0</BASEVISIBILITY>
    <CAPTION>Förderggregat:</CAPTION>
    <CLASSNAME>Reference</CLASSNAME>
    <CLASSNAMESPACE>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.DialogControls</CLASSNAMESPACE>
    <COLWIDTH>200</COLWIDTH>
    <DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>1</DETAILFIELDISNUMERIC>
    <DETAILFIELDNAME>FID_FEATURE_TO</DETAILFIELDNAME>
    <DETAILTABLE>WW_PO_OU_CONVEYING</DETAILTABLE>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <GRIDORDER>0</GRIDORDER>
    <HEIGHT>22</HEIGHT>
    <HIDEATGRID>0</HIDEATGRID>
    <LEFT>180</LEFT>
    <MASTERFIELDNAME>FID</MASTERFIELDNAME>
    <NAME>$REF_WW_PO_OU_CONVEYING</NAME>
    <PRIORITY>100</PRIORITY>
    <PROJECTIONBUTTON>1</PROJECTIONBUTTON>
    <REFERENCEBUTTON>1</REFERENCEBUTTON>
    <TABID>2</TABID>
    <TOP>313</TOP>
    <WIDTH>200</WIDTH>
  </TB_GN_CONTROL>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NAME>Objekt</NAME>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
    <ID>a208ad72-bb0e-410e-8ab1-672a8bf2bb50</ID>
    <BAR_ID>1</BAR_ID>
    <NAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Map.MapDialog/TBDigitizeChildren</NAME>
    <USERGROUP_ID>a0194cac-0b6c-4ed9-a631-aa125c7c950e</USERGROUP_ID>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
    <ID>bf8b2c9c-36bf-48df-9edf-e22dc06d41f0</ID>
    <BAR_ID>1</BAR_ID>
    <NAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Map.MapDialog/TBDigitizeHole</NAME>
    <USERGROUP_ID>a0194cac-0b6c-4ed9-a631-aa125c7c950e</USERGROUP_ID>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
    <ID>fef9076a-ad2f-4ed4-ac43-2681e8273390</ID>
    <BAR_ID>1</BAR_ID>
    <NAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Map.MapDialog/TBDigitize</NAME>
    <USERGROUP_ID>a0194cac-0b6c-4ed9-a631-aa125c7c950e</USERGROUP_ID>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
    <ID>ac567c26-aea2-43c2-9f2e-b83f5b047d62</ID>
    <BAR_ID>1</BAR_ID>
    <NAME>Autodesk.Map.IM.Forms.Basis.BasisDialog/tbb_Delete</NAME>
    <USERGROUP_ID>a0194cac-0b6c-4ed9-a631-aa125c7c950e</USERGROUP_ID>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_BAR_FILTER>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
    <ID>38</ID>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>WW_DISPOSITION_STATE_TBD</PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>
    <PROJECTION_FILTER>ID in (select ID_STATE  from WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE where {Filter})</PROJECTION_FILTER>
    <PROJECTION_NAME>Status</PROJECTION_NAME>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
    <ID>39</ID>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>WW_PO_MA_FUNCTION_TBD</PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>
    <PROJECTION_FILTER>ID in (select ID_FUNCTION  from WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE where {Filter})</PROJECTION_FILTER>
    <PROJECTION_NAME>Funktion</PROJECTION_NAME>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
    <ID>40</ID>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>WW_UTILISATION_TBD</PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>
    <PROJECTION_FILTER>ID in (select ID_UTILISATION  from WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE where {Filter})</PROJECTION_FILTER>
    <PROJECTION_NAME>Nutzung / Wassserart</PROJECTION_NAME>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
  <TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
    <ID>41</ID>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>WW_PO_FI_FITTING</PROJECTION_DIALOG_NAME>
    <PROJECTION_FILTER>FID_FEATURE in (select FID  from WW_PO_MA_MANHOLE)</PROJECTION_FILTER>
    <PROJECTION_NAME>Haltungsverbindung</PROJECTION_NAME>
  </TB_GN_DIALOG_PROJECTION>
  <TB_GN_REPORT>
    <ID>112</ID>
    <DESKTOP>1</DESKTOP>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <FILENAME>Liste Normschacht</FILENAME>
    <NAME>Liste Normschacht</NAME>
    <PROPS>Format=DEFAULT</PROPS>
    <REPORTTYPE>Topobase Report</REPORTTYPE>
    <WEB>0</WEB>
  </TB_GN_REPORT>
  <TB_GN_REPORT>
    <ID>110</ID>
    <DESKTOP>1</DESKTOP>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <NAME>Default</NAME>
    <REPORTTYPE>Default</REPORTTYPE>
    <WEB>0</WEB>
  </TB_GN_REPORT>
  <TB_GN_REPORT>
    <ID>111</ID>
    <DESKTOP>1</DESKTOP>
    <DIALOG_ID>1175</DIALOG_ID>
    <FILENAME>Bericht Normschacht</FILENAME>
    <NAME>Bericht Normschacht</NAME>
    <PROPS>Format=DEFAULT</PROPS>
    <REPORTTYPE>Topobase Report</REPORTTYPE>
    <WEB>0</WEB>
  </TB_GN_REPORT>
  <TB_USERGROUP>
    <ID>5ddd0fea-8554-4665-9f5b-6fa2da3b0b12</ID>
    <NAME>LEHRLING</NAME>
  </TB_USERGROUP>
  <TB_USERGROUP>
    <ID>b19d9a62-25f5-4a1a-a8a3-79b267808830</ID>
    <NAME>ADMIN</NAME>
  </TB_USERGROUP>
  <TB_USERGROUP>
    <ID>5dffd865-1a86-4e06-a716-e646d48a973e</ID>
    <NAME>GR_BENUTZER</NAME>
  </TB_USERGROUP>
  <TB_USERGROUP>
    <ID>a0194cac-0b6c-4ed9-a631-aa125c7c950e</ID>
    <NAME>GR_BETRACHTER</NAME>
  </TB_USERGROUP>
</Topobase>```
````

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this? Simply add two `xsl:sort` instructions: one by `name()` and one by `ID` (with the latter having `data-type="number"`).

Comment: You haven't provided a complete (but smallest possible, please) source XML document and the complete wanted result of the transformation. It is not meaningful to expect people trying to answer the question to invent these

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier to understand your requirements with a more detailed example, but I think this does what you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Topobase">
    <xsl:element name="Topobase">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name()">
            <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:sort select="ID" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can also see it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBh

Comment: Or simply: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBh/1

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm learning a lot from your answers. I'll never get as good an understanding of XSLT as you have, but I try!

Comment: Hi
thanks to all for comments and solution - and sorry for being unprecisely.

a) XSLTFiddle: a fine tool, new for me. Will this link be permanent or only temporarily? Is it also for large files? With 7000 lines I suceeded, with 100.000 lines I failed.

b) the first XSLT-code: Works fine with Saxon, but the other engines give error messages realting "group-by"

c) the second XSLT-code: Works fine 

d) Full example XLM: I added it above to the first question

Comment: @PierredelaVerre `xsl:for-each-group` requires XSLT 2.0. The "other engines" are XSLT 1.0 processors. If you look at my version, you will see that grouping is not necessary in this case.